# Android ActionBar with fragments reload each time

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a main activity with a actionbar, tabs and some fragments. Each time i switch a tab the full fragment is recreated. On some of the fragments i have a listview with content loaded from a webservice, i don't want this to be recalled from the webservice... The listview is a by click listview, so you can navigate through it.

Are fragments the best choice or do i need something else to keep the content stay alive. For example the tabbar from iOS, there every viewcontroller stays alive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Side note:It is a matter of "I want my data to persist" and not "My fragments should stay alive".

Comment: same problem here but I solved, I am posting sample code have a look..

Comment: Where do you have the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know offhand if it's possible to change the behaviour so that the `Fragment`s are made to persist in memory, but I do remember needing to do something similar myself when using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, where it's possible to specify a maximum number of `Fragment`s that the adapter keeps around in memory before it starts destroying them. However, this was a bit of an exceptional case that I did for special reasons.

The proper 'Android way' is to design your `Fragment`s and `Activity` classes so that they can routinely cope with going through the create / destroy cycle, persisting and recalling their state as they do so. You are better off not trying to change the destroy and create behaviour, and instead persist your state data from the `Fragment`s using the existing lifecycle methods designed for the very purpose. The data loaded from the web service should be cached somewhere as appropriate depending on the kind of data it is. What should be realised is that the `Fragment` / `Activity` classes also really need to be able to cope with being destroyed during events such as device rotation. This also happens if the device goes to sleep, or the application goes into the background, etc. Therefore it's hard to get away from the need to persist your state and your web service data between the `onDestroy()` / `onCreate()` cycle.

Comment: Oke, but i remember when i used the tabhost they will stored in memory. And for example when a user scrolls down in a list and clicks on a item and navigates back, the list needs to stay on the same position..